# FreeSwitch: Send image data on SIP body / multipart on call

Tags: sip, multipart, freeswitch, sdp

I'm looking for a way to be able to pass one image data (binary or base64) in a call. Perhaps in the SIP body / multipart SDP in the dialplan since I understand that in the SIP header it is not viable due to size limitations.

The purpose is to be able to display a preview image of the caller on the target device (mobile) so that they can see it before taking or rejecting the call.

Currently, I have the image saved and send it using a push notification when the call occurs but I would like to skip that step and send it over SIP. In this way, you could send the image on the fly without having to store it on the server. For this, I need to know if there is the possibility of sending the image as data using the SIP protocol.

I have been looking at the official documentation without finding anything about it and they have not been able to help me on the "freeswitch users help list" where I have consulted first.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Why sending the whole image via SIP? Send the link(resource URL) to the image.

Comment: @Mirza because I want to avoid storing the image on the server.